# Every time I create a new database it's creating a table in that database

Tags: postgresql

Every time I create a new database it's creating a table in that database. I'm finding information about [model databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-2017) for Microsoft SQL Server, but I can't find anything for Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably created that table in the `template1` database.

When you create a database, Postgres doesn't really create it from scratch, it copies an existing one.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)

> By default, the new database will be created by cloning the standard system database `template1`. A different template can be specified by writing `TEMPLATE name`.

Just connect to the `template1` database and drop the table there.

Comment: You might want to verify that someone hadn't put the table there for a reason, first.